# UniformJS radio buttons not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radio-button, uniform

I've used UniformJS before and am having an issue with radio buttons this time around. I have uniform initialized for only checkbox and radio, and I can check/uncheck checkboxes just fine. My radio buttons are stylized but not showing as clicked. I have no errors in the console, and I'm not sure what the issue could be. I copied the exact radio inputs from the working fiddle, with no luck. http://jsfiddle.net/Wp9kx/ When giving the attribute checked in the tag, it appears as clicked but will not unclick. It seems the click isn't getting pushed through the styling.Any ideas?

```
$("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]").uniform();
```

Comment: Hello triple, did you get solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This will happen if your radio isn't inside a label.

This works:

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" value="option1" />option 1
</label>
```

This doesn't:

```
<input type="radio" value="option1" />option 1
```

Here is the [bug report](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/issues/405).